# Formula to compute the padding in convolutions pytorch (googlenet)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am implementing googlenet (smaller version) from scratch in pytorch.  The architecture is below:

[image]

For the Downsample Module I have the following code:

```
   class DownSampleModule(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, in_channel, ch3, w):
       super(DownSampleModule, self).__init__()
       kernel_size = 3
       padding = (kernel_size-1)/2

       self.branch1 = nn.Sequential(
           ConvBlock(in_channel, ch3, kernel_size = 3,stride=2, padding=int(padding))
       )
       self.branch2 = nn.Sequential(
           nn.MaxPool2d(3, stride=2, padding=0, ceil_mode=True)
       )
   def forward(self, x):
       branch1 = self.branch1(x)
       branch2 = self.branch2(x)
      
       return torch.cat([padded_tensor, branch2], 1)
```

The ConvBlock is from this module

```
class ConvBlock(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
       super(ConvBlock, self).__init__()
       #padding = (kernel_size -1 )/2
       #print(padding)
       self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding)
       self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
       self.act = nn.ReLU()
       
   def forward(self, x):
       x = self.conv(x)
       x = self.bn(x)
       x = self.act(x)
       return x
```

Basically, we are creating two branches: a convolution module and a max pool.  The output of these two branches are then concatenated on the channel dimension.

However, I have the following problem:

- Firstly, we call `self.pool1 = DownSampleModule(in_channel=80, ch3 = 80, w=30)`.  The dimensions of the two branches are similar.  These are:

```
Downsample Convolution:torch.Size([1, 80, 15, 15])
Maxpool Convolution:torch.Size([1, 80, 15, 15])
```

- However, when we call `self.pool2 = DownSampleModule(in_channel = 144, ch3 = 96, w=15)`.  The dimensions are different which prevents it from being concatenated.

```
Downsample Convolution:torch.Size([1, 96, 8, 8])
Maxpool Convolution:torch.Size([1, 144, 7, 7])
```

Does anyone know the formula to compute the correct padding?  Thank you.

In Keras, you can just set the padding="same" or "valid" but it's not supported on pytorch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `maxpool` and `conv` branches have the same input, and will produce identically-shaped output if you give them the same parameters for kernel size, stride and padding. So just replacing your `padding = 0` with `padding = int(padding)` should be enough to make both branches be concat-compatible.

`ceil_mode`should also be set to `False`. When the resulting dimension is not an integer, the rounding behavior of `conv2d` is to use `floor`, so you want your `maxpool` to do that as well.

By the way, you can remove your `nn.Sequential`. Your "sequences" of layers are made of only one layer, so... not really sequential :)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! You're such a big help. Earlier, despite adding similar padding, the dimensions are not thesame.  I just removed the ceil_mode=True.  Thank you! <3

Comment: Thanks for pointing it our, I missed that detail. Updated my answer regarding ceil_mode